# Prioritize relevance over prevalence when suggesting tags

Tags: feature-request, tags

I noticed something annoying when writing a question with the [edition-comparison](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/edition-comparison) tag: the suggested tags box prioritizes prevalence over relevance. If I type "edition" into the tag box, here are my suggestions:

[image]

The desired tag, [edition-comparison](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/edition-comparison), does not get suggested until I've typed "edition-c", but [conversion](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conversion) is still suggested over [edition-comparison](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/edition-comparison):

[image]

I should not have to get all the way to "edition-c" before the only extant tag that starts with "edi" is suggested (only one other tag that starts with "ed").

Comment: This is a double edged sword. If the relevance is defined as "prefer tags that *start* with the search text", then you *lose relevance* when you search for something that the tag doesn't start with. If you thought the tag was "compare-editions" and typed in "compar" the search will push "edition-comparison" down the list of suggestion because it doesn't start with this text.

Comment: @VLAZ Maybe on a stack with thousands of tags. Here, typing “compar” yields exactly one suggestion: [edition-comparison].

Comment: My example was supposed to be more general. Not literally *only* for "compar". The point I make is that if you define "more relevant" to be "starts with" then text that is in the latter part of a tag will be deemed "less relevant". Even if it matches more closely with what you expect.

Comment: @VLAZ Then just make it "contains" instead of "starts with" or build a hierarchy of some sort: start > after hyphen > anywhere > description

Comment: Not an answer because I’m not sure, but I’m about 99% sure that this is not something that can be changed on a site-by-site basis, and even if it is, I’m about 99.9% sure that it’s not something that anyone here has control over. Have you looked around Meta SE on this subject?

Comment: Sadly, you need to ask this on main META, not here, as it is standard stack behavior and we won't get special treatment.

Comment: Trish is correct, you're much more likely to get traction with this over on the [main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/). There's basically no chance this will be implemented for only our site, but if a request for it over on the main meta garners sufficient support it could be rolled out across SE.